# function could not be resolved c++

Tags: c++, function, filter

I am trying to make a more general filter so I defined with typedef a pointer to function. But I receive an error in the DynamicVector* filterByQuantity(int quantity) function. This is the whole code for what I am trying to do:

controller.h

```
typedef int (*filterFunc)(Medicine* criteria, Medicine*);
DynamicVector<Medicine>* filter2(Medicine* criteria, filterFunc f);
```

controller.cpp

```
    #include "controller.h"

int filterByQuantityLess(Medicine* criteria, Medicine* p) {
    if (criteria->getQuantity() > p->getQuantity()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

DynamicVector<Medicine>* Controller::filter2(Medicine* criteria, filterFunc f){
    DynamicVector<Medicine>* medList = repo->getAll();
    DynamicVector<Medicine>* rez = new DynamicVector<Medicine>();
    for(int i=0; i < medList->getLen(); i++){
        Medicine* m = new Medicine(medList->getElementAtPosition(i));
        if(!f(criteria, m)){
            rez->addElement(*m);
        }
    }
    return rez;
}

DynamicVector<Medicine>* filterByQuantity(int quantity){
    Medicine* criteria = new Medicine(1,"",1,quantity);
        DynamicVector<Medicine>* rez = filter2(criteria, filterByQuantityLess); //error

    return rez;
}
```

the error is:
Multiple markers at this line
    - 'filter2' was not declared in this 
     scope
    - Function 'filter2' could not be 
     resolved

Where am I doing wrong? The filter2 function returns a DynamicVector so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: It does not work because you have `Controller::filter2` and not just `filter2` defined... I sure hope this code is not going to be used to prescribe medicine to real people.

Comment: Apart from the acute problem you have, all the "new" stuff will come at you with memory leaks, especially in the presence of exceptions. This is not Java, which has a garbage collection, but C++ which requires you to use smart pointers to get similar behaviour. Instead of pointers, using plain objects is preferable though. Also, you are throwing away the benefits of the compiler checking const-correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Because filter2´s *declaration* and its *implementation* differs.

Look at how you're prototyping it on line 2 and how you implements it. `Filter2` should either be declared as part of the `Controller` scope or as part of the global scope, not both.

Comment: I am doing a modular program. The declaration of filter2 is in controller.h and the implementation in controller.cpp

Comment: @user1849859 That’s irrelevant. You *can* separate them into header and implementation file but you *still* need to declare the function inside the `Controller` class.

Comment: @KonradRudolph And how exactly do I do that? I don't really get it

Comment: @user1849859 Well where do you define the class `Controller`? Stick the function declaration in there.